# Wann wird die richtige Konjunktiv-II-Form bei schwachen Verben verwendet?

Tags: verb, subjunctive

Ich weiß, dass die richtige Konjunktiv-II-Form nur bei einigen starken/gemischten Verben üblich ist, aber wenn sie so benutzt wird, ist klar, dass die im Konjunktiv II stehen:

> Ich hülfe gerne, aber ich muss Maria abholen.
>
> Er wüsste das auch!

Aber bei schwachen Verb kann es unklar sein, ob das Verb im Präteritum oder Konjunktiv steht:

> Das machte ich auch.

Also, werden solche Verben nur so verwendet, wenn es ganz klar ist, dass sie im Konjunktiv stehen?

> Ich wünschte, ich könnte mitmachen
>
> Sie starren mich an, als ob ich eine Bank ausraubte

Frage: Wann kann man schwache Verben in der richtigen Konjunktiv-II-Form verwenden?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In seiner normalen Verwendung als **Irrealis** kann der Konjunktiv II zwar prinzipiell immer statt der würde-Form verwendet werden, aber wie Du schon richtig vermutet hast, besteht bei schwachen Verben eine Verwechslungsgefahr mit dem Präteritum. Deswegen wird dies auch praktisch nie mehr gemacht.

Ein Fall, in dem ich bei schwachen Verben den Konjunktiv II der würde-Form vorziehe, ist in einer Auflistung von Verben im Irrealis. Ein sorgfältig konstruiertes Beispiel:

> Er sagte, der Hund sähe, röche und hörte jeden Einbrecher die Treppe hochkommen. (Das war aber gelogen.)

Wollte ich nur für *hören* die würde-Form verwenden, müsste ich den Nebensatz deutlich umgestalten:

> Er sagte, der Hund sähe und röche jeden Einbrecher die Treppe hochkommen und würde dies auch hören.
>   Er sagte, der Hund sähe und röche jeden Einbrecher die Treppe hochkommen und würde jeden Einbrecher die Treppe hochkommen hören.

Wirklich schön sind diese Alternativen jedoch nicht. (Alternativ kann ich alles in die würde-Form setzen: »Er sagte, der Hund würde jeden Einbrecher die Treppe hochkommen sehen, riechen und hören.«)

Ein weiterer Fall sind Modalverben, bei denen durch Einsatz des Konjunktivs II eine Aneinanderreihung von Infinitiven vermieden werden kann. Ein Beispiel habe ich oben eingeschmuggelt:

> Wollte ich nur für *hören* die würde-Form verwenden, …
>   Würde ich nur *hören* die würde-Form verwenden wollen, …

Oder etwas krasser:

> Wollte ich Auto fahren können, ginge ich in die Fahrschule.
>   Würde ich Auto fahren können wollen, ginge ich in die Fahrschule.

Es gibt aber noch **andere Fälle,** in denen der Konjunktiv II verwendet wird, und in denen er nicht durch die würde-Form ersetzt werden kann, nämlich vor allem feste Redewendungen und die Modalverben, die im Konjunktiv II eine ganz andere Bedeutung haben. In beiden Fällen sind die meisten verwendeten Verben stark, aber eben nicht immer. Zum Beispiel:

> Es sollte gleich regnen.

Hier wird genutzt, dass *sollen* im Konjunktiv II Vermutungen u. Ä. äußerst – »Es würde gleich regnen sollen.« hätte hier eine andere Bedeutung.

> Ich wünschte, ich wäre ein Huhn.

*Wünschen* steht hier ausschließlich aus historischen Gründen im Konjunktiv II und kann weder durch die würde-Form ersetzt werden, noch wird hier bei ähnlichen Verben der Konjunktiv II genutzt: »Ich würde wünschen, ich wäre ein Huhn.« und »Ich ersehnte, dass ich ein Huhn wäre.« haben jeweils andere Bedeutungen. (Die gleiche Bedeutung hätte hier der Indikativ: »Ich wünsche, ich wäre ein Huhn.«)

Comment: Super Antwort, du hast hier schon alles durch und durch erklaert, extrem gut sogar. Aber wie wird das Konjunktiv II benutzt, wenn eine *Irrealis*-Bedeutung nicht gemeint ist, also in der Indirekte Rede? Ist folgendes richtig: "Der Praesident der USA sagte, er wollte nichts damit zu tun haben." Ist das hier Konjunktiv II oder einfach das Praeteritum?

Comment: @Ledda: Der Konjunktiv II wird für die indirekte Rede ja nur genutzt, um eine Verwechslung des Konjunktivs I mit dem Indikativ zu vermeiden (oder als Irrealis). Der Zweck des Konjunktivs II wäre also, Unklarheit über den Modus des Verbs zu vermeiden. Da bei schwachen Verben der Konjunktiv II nicht vom Präteritum unterscheidbar ist, kann er eben dies nicht leisten und deshalb wäre sein Einsatz nicht zielführend. In Deinem Beispiel wäre normale indirekte Rede *wolle; wollte* ist Irrealis – oder nachlässig. (Falls dies nicht war, was Du wissen wolltest, stell vielleicht lieber eine neue Frage.)

Comment: Na ja, du hast das, was ich da geschrieben habe, gut beantwortet aber vielleicht war das etwas unklar. Ich wusste schon, dass man den Konjunktiv II da benutzt, wo es mit dem Konjunktiv I verwechselt werden koennte. Also, nicht "Sie sagten, sie haben es nicht." sondern: "Sie sagten, sie haetten es nicht."

Aber Du hast das Ziel meines Satzes nicht verstanden, und das hat vielleicht selbst schon meine folgende Frage aufgeklaert: Kann man den Konjunktiv II in der Indirekte Rede benutzten, um zwischen dem Praesens und Praeteritum des Konjunktivs zu unterscheiden? Anscheinend nicht!

Comment: Also: "Sie sagte, sie komme nicht, weil ihre Mutter krank wuerde." und nicht wurde, denn sie hat es gesagt und deswegen muss das Verbum in diesem foermlichen Zusammenhang im Konjunktiv stehen. Das hat aber passiert, bevor sie sich drauf entschieden hat, dass sie nicht kommen wollte. Also muss man das mit einem Vergangenheitsform verstaendlich machen. Also nun eine bessere Frage: Benutzt man da lieber den Konjunktiv II oder den Konjunktiv I des Perfekts?

Deutlicher: "weil ihre Mutter krank wuerde" oder "weil ihre Mutter krank worden sei"?

Comment: @Ledda: Deine Beispielsätze sagen vermutlich nicht das aus, was Du sagen möchtest. Stelle bitte eine eigene Frage, in der Du ausführlich beschreibst, was die Sätze aussagen sollen – gerne auch auf Englisch. Vorweg: Es gibt kein »Präteritum des Konjunktivs«. Es gibt nur den Konjunktiv II, dessen Form aus der Präteritumsform abgeleitet wird und der manchmal verwirrenderweise »Konjunktiv Präteritum« genannt wird.

Answer (score 1):

Meiner Ansicht nach ist die Antwort:

> Als Witz und wenn man wie ein Theaterschauspieler klingen will

Ausnahmen sind die Modalverben und ein paar feste Phrasen, die seit Jahrhunderten benutzt werden und für die jeder weiß, dass es sich um einen Konjunktiv handelt. Ein Beispiel ist das von dir bereits genannte "Ich wünschte...".

Im normalen Sprachgebrauch ist die Konjunktiv 2 Form schwacher Verben total unidiomatisch, und ich glaube, dass es einige Menschen gibt, die nicht verstehen, was du meinst, denn um solche Konjunktive nicht als Präteritum zu verstehen, muss man viel gelesen haben (Litaratur, Drama). Sonst ist man mit dieser Bedeutung einfach nicht vertraut genug.

Comment: Die Frage ist: Wann wird die K2-Form verwendet und du sagst "Ich wünschte ist unidiomatisch". Äh?! Nein! Das ist absolut gängig. Und was meinst du mit "denn um solche KOnjunktive nicht als Präteritum zu verstehen, muss man viel gelesen haben" --- Ich wünschte, du hättest dich hier ein wenig präziser ausgedrückt.

Comment: @Em1... das war missverständlich formuliert. Ich meine der K2 ist von "normalen" Verben unidiomatisch. Danke für's finden. Was das andere angeht... "Hey guck mal der Benz da." "Hach... Hätt ich Geld. Ich kaufte so einen." So was zu verstehen braucht ein wenig Erfahrung mit der Form und die kriegt man nicht von RTL.