# Konjunktiv oder Indikativ bei der Übersetzung englischer Bedingungsätze (second conditional)?

Tags: grammar, subjunctive

> It would be better if you studied more.

Wenn man diesen Satz übersetzen würde, welche der folgenden Möglichkeiten wäre korrekt?

> Es wäre besser, wenn du mehr lernst.
>   Es wäre besser, wenn du mehr lerntest.

---

Wenn der Satz auf Englisch lauten würde:

> It would be better if he studied more.

welche der folgenden Übersetzungen wäre richtig und warum?

> Es wäre besser, wenn er mehr lernt.
>   Es wäre besser, wenn er mehr lerne.
>   Es wäre besser, wenn er mehr lernte.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Im Gegensatz zum Englischen stehen im Deutschen beide Hälften eines irrealen Bedingungsgefüges im gleichen Modus, nämlich dem Konjunktiv II (bzw. ersatzweise in der *würde*-Form). Korrekt ist also z. B.:

> Es wäre besser, wenn du mehr äßest.
>   It would be better, if you ate more.

Ich habe jetzt erstmal bewusst nicht Dein Beispiel gewählt, da hier als zusätzliche Schwierigkeit auftaucht, dass der Konjunktiv II und das Imperfekt von *lernen* identisch lauten, nämlich *lerntest.* In so einem Fall wird der Konjunktiv II fast immer durch die *würde*-Form ersetzt (siehe [diese Frage](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/9129/2594) für Ausnahmen). Korrekt ist also:

> Es wäre besser, wenn du mehr lernen würdest.

Analog ist es in Deinem zweiten Beispiel:

> Es wäre besser, wenn er mehr lernen würde.

Noch ein paar Anmerkungen:

- In beiden Beispielen liegen im Englischen irreale Bedingungsätze (second conditional) vor. Die potentiellen Bedingungssätze (in denen es möglich ist, dass *du* bzw. *er* mehr lernen; first conditional) und ihre Übersetzungen sind:

  > It will be better if you learn more.
  >   Es ist besser, wenn Du mehr lernst.
  >
  > It will be better if he learns more.
  >   Es ist besser, wenn er mehr lernt.
- Im zweiten Beispiel ist *lerne* (dein zweiter Vorschlag) ein Konjunktiv I, der in beiderlei Bedingungssätzen generell nichts verloren hat.

Comment: Eine Gegenanmerkung: Es liegen potentialis-Sätze vor. Die, die du verbessert hast, heißen realis. Irrealis wäre »It would *have been* better, if you *had learnt* more« gewesen.

Comment: @Jan: Das wäre Irrealis der Vergangenheit (third conditional), siehe z. B. [hier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_clause#English).

Comment: Naja … im 3rd conditional ist es unmöglich, noch zu lernen, weil die Prüfung schon vergeigt wird. Im 2nd ist es noch möglich, obwohl die Prüfung nahe liegt, im 1st ist die Prüfung noch weit weg. Sowohl 2nd als auch 1st zeigen eine Möglichkeit an, bei keinem ist der Zug abgefahren. Wenn das wirklich inzwischen *irrealis* genannt wird (ich erinnere mich aus Schulzeiten an etwas anderes), verstehe ich den Begriffssinn nicht mehr ^^'